# <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css"> not working

Tags: html, css

I am cleaning up my web portfolio directory by placing CSS, images etc into respective folders.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">
```

However, I can't seem to load certain DIV elements from my CSS file if it's inside a directory.

The DIV is below:

```
#contact-form-wrap {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('img/form-bg.png')  no-repeat;
    min-height: 768px;
}
```

Is there a way of solving this? Everything else seems to load except for the div above.

Comment: Are you saying that the background image doesn't load, or that none of the style settings for the div are applied? (If you set a background colour does it work? Do you get any error messages in your browser's console?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
#contact-form-wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../img/form-bg.png)  no-repeat;
  min-height: 768px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have maybe inline CSS which overwrites external style ?

Comment: Your answer worked! Why is that the case? Is there some sort of indexing problem with the CSS and Images ?

Comment: When you're putting styles in css folder than in css document you call images like above, and when your css document is in root out of folder than you call images `background: url("images/image.png")`.

Comment: Paths in the css are relative to the css document and not the html document. So `img/form-bg.png` is actually `css/img/form-bg.png` what `../img/form-bg.png` does is move up one folder (because of the `.../`).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using the ID and not a class when using #contact-form-wrap. That is the only thing I can really think of.

**Example:**

Incorrect:

```
<div class="contact-form-wrap"></div>
```

Correct:

```
<div id="contact-form-wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add `type="text/css"` to your css declaration like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css">
```

Comment: Not necessary in HTML5.